# Retrieve data from database in Uri form?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have an image uri using this uri i insert image in the sqlite DataBase but the problem is how can i retrieve image .

this is code:

```
if(data!=null){
    Uri uri = data.getData();

    try {

        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();

        DataBase dataBase=new DataBase(getBaseContext());
        dataBase.insertImage(bArray);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"single item  ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

i want to retrive image??

Answer (score 0):

> android docs :
>
> abstract byte[]   getBlob(int columnIndex) Returns the value of the
>   requested column as a byte array.

Example:

```
Cursor resultSet = mydatbase.rawQuery("Select * from TutorialsPoint",null);
resultSet.moveToFirst();
byte[] raw_image = resultSet.getBlob(1)
```